# how to nest a opengl window in my qMainWindow

Tags: qt, opengl

I want to nest a opengl window in my qMainWindow and connect with it.Now I just know use WinId to get the pointer to my qwidget,Please someone give me some advices.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the usual method. Create the QGLWidget instance with the QMainWindow instance passed as parent. If you want to put it into some layout, use the layout instance's `addWidget` method on the QGLWidget's instance.

Comment: Actually,I need nest the opengl window created by others in my qtwidget,and send some orders to  opengl window

Comment: @CrystalJake: For sending orders you can introduce new public slots and public signals you can freely connect between QObjects that share no direct relationship whatsoever. As for the nesting structure, I suggest you draw a little picture to illustrate your needs.

Comment: How to upload picture?I want to implement a function,Part of My MainWindow can display the opengl,but the opengl display function has been finished by others,so I need to nest opengl window into my MainWindow.

Comment: @CrystalJake: You can use a service like http://imgur.com and post the image link in your question. The usual approach to what you want is creating the QGLWidget as a child widget of the main window.